# Exit Jersey initialization on illegal annotation

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm using jersey 2.8. Sometimes, I make a mistake in an annotation like the invalid "]" in the following code

```
@GET
@Path("/{version]/foo")
public String doSomething(@PathParam("version") String version) {
   ...
}
```

Jersey then complains:

> WARNING: Illegal character "]" at position 9 is not allowed as a part of a name in a path template "/{version]".

However, this is not an exception that is passed on to my code, so the program can stop initialization early. In fact, I haven't found a way to get notified of such errors and react accordingly at all. I consider this type of error fatal. Can I make it stop initialization somehow?

Edit: The warning I get is at *runtime* and I would like to have an *exception* instead.

Comment: Do you have any automation build system (maven, gradle)?

Answer (score -1):

Add compiler option -Werror to maven compiler plugin.

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-Werror</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Your build fails if any warning occurs.

Comment: That doesn't help. Sorry, my description might have been not precise enough. What I'm getting is a _runtime_ warning (as jersey is scanning through the annotations), not a compiler warning. I'd like to have an exception (again at runtime) instead.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. I think that there is no way to catch runtime warning log from app. But if you want, you can write your logs into file and write some logs analyzer which will shutdown your app if any warning appears.